# How to look ahead multiple steps while reading files in C++

Tags: c++, file, newline, delimiter

I have an input file that consists of multiple integers separated by white spaces or newline characters.
EX:

```
7\n
2 2\n
3 4\n
\n
8\n
3 1\n
5 6\n
7 7\n
\n
3\n
1 2\n
3 4\n
```

.... and so on.

I need to decide how many different input sets I have based on this input file. I am unable to do this. Any tips?

Comment: Each input set is basically separated by 2 newline characters

Comment: Do you just want to count the number of input sets?  Or are you planning to read all the input sets into some kind of data structure?

Answer (score 5):

Read the file line by line. After each read, check what the next character in the stream is. If it's `'\n'` (or EOF), you're at the end of input set.

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream stream;
size_t sets = 0;

while (std::getline(stream, line)) {

    // do something with line

    int next = stream.get()
    if (next == '\n' || next == EOF)
        ++sets;
    else
        stream.putback(next);
}
```